# What is HTTP Status code 000?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, akamai

Just switched some downloads over to the Akamai CDN network and I'm seeing some strange stuff in the log files they deliver. A number of entries have the status code 000. When I asked them they said that 000 is the status when the client disconnects without transferring the entire file. Since 000 doesn't appear to be a valid HTTP response code (from the RFC), I have to wonder if that's right.

Comment: It's their logfile, they can make 000 mean whatever they want it to mean. Do you have a reason to think they're lying to you?

Comment: It seems to be some kind of custom extension from Akamai. So far I think the client will get the response code 200.

Comment: Wooble : not lying to me but I've had plenty of cases where the people on the front lines of support don't always have all of the information. FWIW, the log file is *supposed* to be a standard "combined" log format file. It'd be pretty strange for them to break from the standards, especially since those error codes will throw any analytic software off (that's how I learned about the problem in the first place).

Answer (score 28):

There's a [knowledge base article](https://control.akamai.com/portal/kb/kbSearchDetails.jsf?articleId=4756) (requires login) which lists their log values:

> **Log Delivery Services (LDS)** LDS will show a 000 for any 200 or 206
>   responses with a client abort: the object  was served correctly from
>   the origin or edge, but the end-user terminated the 
>   connection/transaction before it completed.

This is indeed a custom status because the standard log format doesn't include a field which can indicate a client abort.

Answer (score 16):

000 is a common code to use when no HTTP code was received due to a network error. According to a [knowledge base article for Amazon CloudFront](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=44036), 000 also means that the client disconnected before completing the request for that service.

Answer (score 6):

It normally means: No valid HTTP response code 
(ie: Connection failed, or was aborted before any data happened).

I would guess that their are either network issues or Akamai isn't managing their webservers correctly.

Comment: It's pretty hard to believe that Akamai would do anything non-standard with logging seeing as they're one of the biggest (and oldest) CDN providers out there. Anything is possible I guess...